# VB.NET - There is no row at position 1 - datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to have the contents of a datatable be displayed in a listbox. I cannot, however, figure out what is wrong with my code; I am pretty sure I have tried every way but the right way. I have search through StackOverflow, and the internet in general for an answer, but I cannot find any relevent information. The error I keep getting is:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: There is no row at position 1.

```
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count()
            lstBoxSaved.Items.Add((dt.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString) & " " &
                       (dt.Rows(i).Item(1).ToString))
        Next i
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please clear table", "error: too many entries")
    End If
```

Some while ago I was able to get some variant of this to work for one item, but I need to display all items in the datatable. If there is a more efficient way to display an entire row that would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're problem is that the way your loop is written it goes past the last element, which is where the exception is thrown.  For example, if you have 1 row in the table the index of that row in the collection of rows is 0.  The first time the loop happens, `dt.Rows(i)` will get the first row in the table (index 0).  The next time the loop happens, `i` will be 1.  So when `dt.Rows(i)` happens again, it's trying to grab the *second* row in the table, which does not exist.  So, because the rows are indexed starting at 0, you want to loop to the number of rows *minus 1*.

`For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count()` should be `For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count() - 1`

Comment: Or better use a foreach row in dt.Rows to avoid any problem

Comment: Eugene... its better to explain it a little so he knows what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you Eugene. I think I understand why, the count has to be one less than the number of rows because the first row starts at zero, correct? I cannot believe it was such a simple fix.

Comment: @logixologist I've added some more details about what was going wrong to better explain things.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @michaelkiddy Exactly

Answer (score 0):

I add a checkbox to grid and check if the checkbox is checked. After that I add select rows to list box.

```
Dim I As Integer
For I = 0 To DataG1.Rows.Count - 2
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataG1.Rows(I)

    Dim Check As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = row.Cells(0)

    Dim ID As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = row.Cells(1)
    Dim Name As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = row.Cells(2)
    If Check.Value = True Then
        lstBoxSaved.Items.Add(ID ,Name )
    End If
Next
```